# Append text to an Excel file

Tags: r

I have an excel file that I alread wrote code to. I want to add another line of code. Suppose, I want to add "Hello" under the data already there. I tried:

```
write.xlsx("Hello", "text.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", append = TRUE)
```

And got the error:

```
Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;", "createSheet",  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name
```

I was wondering how I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex you want to get here is a simple way to load your text into excel

```
path = r'ENTER FILE PATH AND DESIRED FOLDER NAME HERE FOLLOWED BY .csv' #plug in  the     
folder path you want to save this as ending it with the filename.csv of your choice
with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as resultfile:
wr = csv.writer(resultfile, dialect='excel')
wr.writerow([x[0] for x in cursor.description])

for record in records:
  wr.writerow(record)
```

Comment: or if you want xlsx write the following:  path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test12345.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
crsr.close()
conn.close()